# How to keep HABTM with TranslateBehaviour in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, translate

I have a model "Report" where some fields are translatable through TranslateBehaviour.
Each Report "Has And Belongs To Many" ReportTags and ReportCategories.

In my ReportsController, I try to add a new Report to DB with:

```
public function admin_add() {
if ($this -> request -> is('post')) {
    $this -> Report -> create();
    if ($this -> Report -> saveMany($this -> request -> data)) {
        $this -> Session -> setFlash(__('Report saved OK'), 'flash/backend/success');
        return $this -> redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Report saved KO. Please, try again'), 'flash/backend/error');
    }
}
$users = $this->Report->User->find('list');
$reportCategories = $this->Report->ReportCategory->find('list');
$reportTags = $this->Report->ReportTag->find('list');
$this->set(compact('users', 'reportCategories', 'reportTags'));
$this->set('title',__('New report'));
$this->set('item_selected',4);
}
```

But doing this I add three reports to Reports table, the one I want to add and two more empty.
i18n table adds the correct rows for translations (one per locale and translatable field), but also the rows with fields for the two empty models added, with "content" field empty.

How can I add only the right values?
I tried also to do

```
unset($this->request->data['ReportCategory']);
unset($this->request->data['ReportTag']);
```

before saveMany, but this eliminates associations between Report, ReportCategory and ReportTag.

For more info, $this -> request -> data contains:

```
array(3) { 
["Report"]=> array(11) { 
    ["published"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["sticky"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["in_rss"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["slug"]=> string(4) "asdf" 
    ["media_uri"]=> string(4) "ssss" 
    ["title"]=> array(3) {  
        ["spa"]=> string(3) "www" 
        ["eng"]=> string(3) "eee" 
    } 
    ["summary"]=> array(3) { 
        ["spa"]=> string(3) "www" 
        ["eng"]=> string(3) "eee" 
    } 
    ["body"]=> array(3) { 
        ["spa"]=> string(12) "www" 
        ["eng"]=> string(12) "eee" 
        } 
    } 
["ReportCategory"]=> array(1) { 
    ["ReportCategory"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "7" 
    } 
} 
["ReportTag"]=> array(1) { 
    ["ReportTag"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(2) "23" 
        [1]=> string(2) "24" 
    } 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Problem was saveMany. It must be replaced by saveAll. I use saveMany in other controllers when there are HasMany associations, to save the array of translations for translatable fields. In HABTM associations, this does not work. Hope this helps to somebody.